# What is the right way to do a get request to an existing database from a Go API

Tags: mysql, api, rest, go

I am new in Golang and I am cooking up an API that can get an item from an existing database using golang as the primary language. The code structure I have done is shown below, please help on how to perform get requests for certain information in an already existing DB.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"
    "go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

 
// Configure the database connection (always check errors)
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "admin:*******@(******)/dbname?parseTime=true")


// Initialize the first connection to the database, to see if everything works correctly.
// Make sure to check the error.
err := db.Ping()
```

After initializing the DB, what code can I add to that can do two things:

- First, call all clients in the DB
- Second, call a single client in the DB using the ID number.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type User struct {
    Id string
    Name string
}

func getAll() (users []User) {
    users = []User{}

    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT id, name FROM clients`)

    if err != nil {
        //some error handling        
        return
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        user := User{}

        err = rows.Scan(
            &user.Id,
            &user.Name,
        )

        if err != nil {
            // error handling
            return
        }

        users = append(users, user)
    }

    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        //error handling
    }
    
    return
}

func Get(id int64) (user User) {
    user = User{}
    
    err = db.QueryRow(`SELECT id, name FROM cliets WHERE id = ?`, id).Scan(
        &user.ID,
        &user.Name,            
    )

    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        //not found error
    case err != nil:
        //bad request error
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: Oh this is awesome. but assuming, I want to return status code for JSOn files, how does that work? Incase I am doing a postman test